# OpsHub mirgation failure OpsHub-012310: Work item does not exist

Tags: opshub

Trying to use OpsHub (free version) to migrate from on-prem TFS to VSTS. It is failing on a work item with the following error:

> com.opshub.exceptions.eai.EAITFSPollerException: OpsHub-012310: Error
>   occurred in getting link/attachment information for WorkItem 46906
>   Revision 1. Caused By OH-TFS-Connector-0051: Operation failed
>   getLinkInformation. Server Error : TF26198: The work item does not
>   exist, or you do not have permission to access it.

I am able to access the work item. I did see the work item had 3 associated work items and I verified I could open all of those as well.

Any suggestions? I did get this with a few other work items and I purged them. I would like to know the cause as I anticipate running into this issue again and the process of manually removing the work items is costly as I do not have a list of all the problem work items. I have to resume the migration and wait for it to error.

Update: I have been able to identify the culprit. This work item is linked to another work item in a different project. Surprisingly I can't see that item even though I have collection admin. I'll keep working on it. I know the linked work item exists.

Comment: Access permission is most likely the case. The tool is being able to detect the link but cannot read the linked WIT for information. Thus, probably not able to decide if it's in the same project or not.

Comment: Turns out I was not collection admin. After resolving that the migration completed successfully. If you want to post that as the answer I will give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Justin confirmed himself, the issue was Access Permission. The user through which the migration was running, could access the WIT in question and it's links. But could not access the linked WIT (which was from another project). Providing the permission to the migration user, by making him the 'Project Collection Administrator' solved the issue.